# Self-archiving of a preprint whose title has changed in the journal version

Tags: arxiv, google-scholar, preprint

After a revision that included a change in the title, I recently got my last paper accepted. The policy of the editor about arXiv is that self-archiving is allowed at any time for preprints, but only after 1 year embargo for postprint.

Because I would like to make my paper more accessibile, I'm keen on archiving the preprint right now, and wait till next year to upload the final (but of course still unedited) postprint.

My question is: which title should I put in the metadata during the arXiv submission? Is that OK to use the final title even though the preprint title is different? And if I use the old title for 1 year until I'am allowed to upload the postprint, will google scholar eventually understand that? Will preprint, postprint and journal paper appear as different versions of the same thing (including the citation list)?

Comment: You can always write in the notes section: "published in (blah) under the title [new title]". You should be adding the journal reference in any case in the relevant field (and doi if there is one). If you merely change the title and not the content of the article from the preprint version I doubt the journal will sue you or whack you with the DMCA.

Comment: Most likely you can just ignore the policy and nothing bad will happen. It's probably a bad idea to update the title without updating the paper, since it will make readers mistake the preprint for the actual paper.